# Generate 1000 pairs of random numbers and tabulate each pair like 00, 01, 02, …, 99

Tags: c

I want to generate 10,000 pairs of numbers between 0 and 9. Like 00, 01, 02, 03... 99. I tried with the following function but it did not produce the desired results.

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    rand_num = (int)(100.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+ 1.0));
    printf (" %d ", rand_num);
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Do you want a C answer or  C++ answer?

Comment: I want this in C lan

Comment: If you're not really concerned about perfect randomness: `rand() % 100`.

Comment: @tadman I believe (am not 100% certain) that as long as rand() is guaranteed to generate **uniform** (pseudo) random numbers, then rand()%100 will indeed be _"perfectly random"_  in that [0,100) range. And just curious, especially if I'm wrong: why do you think not?

Comment: @JohnForkosh A) `rand()` is absolute trash on some systems with `RAND_MAX` taking on comically low values. B) Unless `RAND_MAX % 100 == 0` then you will have a very slight bias towards some of the numbers. It is absolutely not "perfectly random". It is, at best, random-ish. In comparison, C++ does have perfectly even distribution generators, but you have to ask for them.

Comment: @tadman Okay, I see your point(s). But that bias becomes vanishingly small as RAND_MAX gets sufficiently large, which it typically is. Heck, like you say, I wouldn't use a rand() with a (comically) low RAND_MAX to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: if an answer helps you please click the green checkmark on that answer to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It's how stackexchange works. Please spend 1 minute to take the [tour] for more information on how SE works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "printf" like this

```
 printf("%02d\n", rand_num);
```

It will print 0 before the number if the number is less than two digits.And of course you can replace'*2*'with any number.

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there any way to generate two-digit random numbers between 0 to 9? I want this result put into the int array

Comment: You could use "rand()"get a random numbers that we call "x" ,then do "x%10".Or you can turn "100 *rand ()" to "10 *rand()".

Answer (score 2):

If you want zero prefix just tell `printf` to do that

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    rand_num = (int)(100.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+ 1.0));
    printf (" %02d ", rand_num);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:11),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3B+i%3C1000%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++int+rand_num+%3D+(int)(100.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX%2B+1.0))%3B%0A++++++++printf+(%22+%2502d+%22,+rand_num)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g122,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

[Read the documentation on the format specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: You beat me! Good call on the "%02d"` specifier `:)`

Comment: good one. one more question :). I want to put these results into an int array without printing the values.

Comment: @mihiran an int is an int. It just contains the value, not the precision or representation. The representation depends on what you want on printing time. 12, 014, 0001100, 0x0C, +00000000012... are all the same value in different bases and formats. It's just impossible to store the format in the int variable

Comment: Is there any way to get two-digit random numbers between 0 to 9? @phuclv

Comment: `rand() % 10`, as tadman said, or adjust your expression to `10.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+ 1.0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
    char d1 = '0' + rand()%10;
    char d2 = '0' + rand()%10;
    printf("%c%c ", d1, d2);
}
printf("\n");
```